# Can we use https instead of http with networkimageview.setImageUrl?

Tags: android, http, https, android-permissions, networkimageview

I am using volley's networkimageview to render images from network in android. I am using networkimageview.setImageUrl(str_url,imageLoader) where 'str_url' is string which contains url and 'imageLoader' is a object of ImageLoader. When it is 'http' url, it displays images properly. But if I tried to use any 'https' url, it will not display images on screen.

Does it needs any extra permissions in manifest to use 'https' or anything else?

Any help on this issue could be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes. ofcourse you can use https url.. are u getting any error?

Comment: I did not get any error.. In the logs it shows the correct url path. But not able to display image on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , it should work but website should also support https, check whether https port is available or not on particular URL.
Please check URL(Image link) by opening it with https in browser.

Comment: I checked it too. The images are opening in browser. But not in my app.

Comment: ok , Are you able to connect with URL with HTTPS and Success code 200 ?